# Language translation issue in GitHub project

Tags: c#

I'm having problems with the translated language of my project on GitHub, my project is all in C# but when I go up with git to GitHub it says it's in JavaScript, I found other people trying to solve it with the .gitattributes file but I didn't I achieved

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Aqui é o Stack Overflow em Português. Por favor, traduza sua pergunta.

Comment: Também ajudaria se você descrevesse mais sobre os objetivos dos códigos, colocar algum de exemplo, etc. e como você sobe ele para o github.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você está utilizando o https://github.com/anuraghazra/github-readme-stats? Se for, eu fiz uma alteração na minha pagina principal da seguinte forma:

```
<img height="160em" src="https://github-readme-stats.vercel.app/api/top-langs/?username=leandropaixao&layout=compact&langs_count=20&theme=tokyonight&hide=javascript,html,css,scss,mako,less" />
```

Na `url` tem a opcao `HIDE` na qual você informa as extensões das linguagens ou arquivos que não quer que contabilize e apareça no gráfico.

Para o segundo item não tem muito o que fazer no caso.